# How to do average in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Problem: we want to take the average of salaries stored in a text file. Assume that the file contains firstname, lastname and salary. Lets say we want to do this for all companies, all sizes in US. A new file is started for a new day ie all salaries entered on April 29 are in a file titled April29.txt and all salaries entered on April 30 are in file titled April30.text and so on. You can imagine each day the line numbers will be different.

Goal: Calculate the average salary per file using mapreduce.

Now everywhere I look the overall suggestion to do average is this:
map reads one line at a time and outputs "key", value
because there is only one key - "key" all output goes to ONE reducer where we use a for loop to compute the average.

This approach is great except that the bigger the file gets the worst the computation time becomes. Is there a way to improve this situation? I didn't find an example that address this situation but if you know some please share a link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a perfect situation for a combiner. That should ideally reduce the processing time a bit.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that a combiner will run however, right?

Answer (score 3):

This can definitely be done more efficiently.

Now, we know the `Mapper` has a `map` method you can override.  However, it also has a `cleanup`.  Looking at the source of the mapper, you see this:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);
  while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
    map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
  }
  cleanup(context);
}
```

So we can use this cleanup method to optimize our average code a bit.

First you need a custom writable that stores two things, `count` and `sum`.  Let's call it `AverageWritable`.  Then, we'll do something like this in the mapper:

```
AverageWritable avg = new AverageWritable();
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context ctx) {
    long salary = [ ... code to get salary... ]
    avg.addCount(1);
    avg.addSum(salary);
}

public void cleanup(Context ctx) {
    ctx.write(CONSTANT_KEY, avg);
}
```

The reducer and combiner code should be easy enough to figure out from here.

Comment: clever use of cleanup method

Answer (score 0):

I was curious as can we do it using the counters provided by hadoop.
Say we build two counters like

public enum CountCounters {
Counter
}

public enum SumCounters {
Counter
}

From within the map method of our mapper, we can access the counter and increment it.

context.getCounter(CountCounters.Counter).increment(1);
context.getCounter(SumCounters.Counter).increment();

and at last we will

job.getCounters().findCounter(CountCounters.Counter).getValue();
job.getCounters().findCounter(SumCounters.Counter).getValue();

and find the average